# www to non-www for subdomains

Tags: redirect, subdomain, no-www

I have a domain and two subdomains, each with it's own wordpress installation. I'd like to redirect the www to non-www for domain and the two subdomains. In its current form, my htaccess rules only work for the domain level.
I have these settings in my .htaccess file on domain level:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.electricmura\.ro [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://electricmura.ro/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.electricmura\.ro)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this only works for the domain level, not for the two subdomains.

- [www.electricmura.ro](http://www.electricmura.ro) redirects to http://electricmura.ro/
- [www.mca.electricmura.ro/](http://www.mca.electricmura.ro/) gives a "We can't connect to the server" error (Firefox) or "www.mca.electricmura.ro’s server IP address could not be found." (Chrome)

Comment: You are offtopic here as it is not a programming problem. You start your rules with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.electricmura\.ro [NC]` so they all apply only to `www.electricmura.ro` and no other website. As for `www.mca.electricmura.ro` it does not resolve at all so you first have a DNS resolution problem, nothing related to Apache.

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickMevzek for suggestion the solution. And I apologise for being offtopic, I guess I am not familiar with the strict definition of programming, pardon my blunder.